# New Date() returns invalid date

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, date

I'm trying to calculate a difference between 2 days using jQuery. The input fields are the Bootstrap datepicker ones.

When I console.log the field values, they give me a date an in the format dd-mm-yyyy

**Code:**

```
console.log($("#actie_begin").val());
```

**Logs**:

> 27/06/2016

However when I try to use a ***new date()*** (to do the calculations) on it, the variable becomes 'Invalid date'

**Code:**

```
var start_date = new Date($("#actie_begin").val());
```

**Logs**:

> Invalid Date

How can I solve this?

Comment: Can you post the markup too please?

Comment: The logged format is not `dd-mm-yyyy` but `dd/mm/yyyy`. Try to output like `dd-mm-yyyy`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The format you use is not supported by [`Date.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse).
You could extract the date parts and call the Date(year, month, day) constructor

```
var starts = $("#actie_begin").val();
var match = /(\d+)\/(\d+)\/(\d+)/.exec(starts)
var start_date = new Date(match[3], match[2], match[1]);
```

Comment: yes that was it. I had to change the dating format. thanks to the bootstrap datepicker all I had to do was '"format: 'yyyy-mm-dd',"

Comment: thanks. it works! on the example above, it should have been starts instead of dates.

Comment: var match = /(\d+)\/(\d+)\/(\d+)/.exec(starts);