# Calculate Date But Result (return) Still Nan

Tags: javascript, datepicker

This is my **HTML**

```
<input type="text" class="dateofbirthpicker">
<input type="text" id="usia">
```

**Script**

```
$(function() {
    $('.dateofbirthpicker').datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'yyyy/mm/dd'
    });
});

window.onload=function() {
    $('.dateofbirthpicker').on('change', function() {
        var dob = new Date(this.value);
        var today = new Date();

        var age = Math.floor((today-dob) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 360));
        ages = parseInt(age);
        $('#usia').val(ages);
    });
}
```

I have the above script to calculated age from date. It is returning age in Firefox but returns `NaN` in Chrome.

I was doing this [Jquery Date.parse returning NaN in Chrome browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7964922/jquery-date-parse-returning-nan-in-chrome-browser)

Result was invalid date when i ran the following...

```
var dob = new Date(this.value);
```

Comment: still can't .. when i run this >> var dob = +new Date(this.value) the result is : invalid date .. any suggest ? @Rayon

Comment: @tara [Seems to run fine in Chrome](https://jsfiddle.net/ko7n1kcs/), are you sure `this.value` is a valid parameter for the Date constructor?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6471959/jquery-datepicker-onchange-event-help

Comment: @tara which date picker u r using ??

Comment: yes .. its working on firefox .. but cant working on chrome .. i think, im sure @SpencerWieczorek

Comment: Simple solution: `dateFormat: 'yy/mm/dd'` as `yyyy` will give date as `20162016-mm-dd`

Comment: guys .. when i select date 1-12 can calculate into age . but when i select date 13-30 .. can't calculate

Comment: i was edit with .. your solution.. it cant .. :( @Rayon

Comment: any solution about this var dob = new Date(this.value)

Comment: @Tara can you add a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) that reporoduces the problem?

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek, It returns date as `"2014/07/08"`

Comment: in js fiddle working fine .. @Ivar

Answer (score 2):

Change your dateformat as `dateFormat: 'yy/mm/dd'`

From [*specs*](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#utility-formatDate),

- **y** - year (two digit)
- **yy** - year (four digit)

```js
$(function() {
  $('.dateofbirthpicker').datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'yy/mm/dd',
    onSelect: function() {
      var dob = new Date(this.value);
      var today = new Date();
      var age = Math.floor((today - dob) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 360));
      ages = parseInt(age);
      $('#usia').val(ages);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.8.18/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.8.21/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<input type="text" class="dateofbirthpicker">
<input type="text" id="usia">
```

### [JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rayon_1990/8w8v9/1666/)

Comment: yes i was try still can't var dob = new Date(this.value) .......
@rayon : invalid date.. i think its problem :((((((

Comment: I'm just going to add a reason why, [for the date-picker a single `y` represents 2 digits](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#utility-formatDate) and not one. So `'yyyy/mm/dd'` isn't valid.

Comment: @tara, Can you specify what is invalid ? I have provided working fiddle and snippet for you! You can highlight the issue over here..

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek, We edited by the same time probably  or you were quicker by couple of seconds! Thanks anyways! ;)

Comment: @tara, Could you reproduce the same in snippet I have provided ?

Comment: yes it work.. but i can't do my mine .. work when select date 1-12.. but 13-30 its invalid date .. in mozilla working .. in chrome didnt work

Comment: i dont know .. because on mozilla working fine but in chrome can't

Comment: @tara, Did you change `dateFormat: 'yy/mm/dd'` ?

Comment: @tara, Now what is the issue ? I have provided fiddle as well!

Comment: but cant in mine .. wait .. im still search too the answer why.. cant in chrome

Comment: Rayon thanks for the discussion .. i get my answer ... thanks so much

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all for discussion and suggest .. i get my answer, from here
[New Date() returns invalid date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38039656/new-date-returns-invalid-date)

```
  $(function() {
    $('.dateofbirthpicker').datepicker({
            dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy'
          });
  });
  window.onload=function(){
    $('.dateofbirthpicker').on('change', function() {
          var dselect = $(".dateofbirthpicker").val();
          var match = /(\d+)\/(\d+)\/(\d+)/.exec(dselect);
          var dob = new Date(match[3], match[2], match[1]);
          var today = new Date();

          var age = Math.floor((today-dob) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 360));
      $('#usia').val(age);
    });
  }
```

Comment: `dateFormat` decides the date value accessed using `.val()` method.. There is not need to test it through RegEx

Comment: but .. if i do this --->>>  var dob = new Date(this.value); --->> invalid date

Comment: Because you have not specified valid for =mat which is being accepted for `new Date`